# Why does Google Dev Tools mobile viewer show something different than actual mobile?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, mobile, navigation

I built a React site and made a full screen navigation. On Google Chrome Dev Tools mobile viewer, it shows the correct spacing but when I push to prod and look at it on my phone, the spacing disappears. Any idea what would cause this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: old question, but we need to see your code to understand what you're doing and what the problem may be. otherwise, if you've found a solution you may consider answering this yourself for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly think maybe you can try to add more spaces. Or, add a separate pc site and a separate mobile one.